# Are VB property declarations without Get and Set the same as C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

This question is about what is created by the different types of VB property declaration syntax.  But first I want to make reference to C# for some context.  I'm not very capable with C#, but I see that we can write:

```
public string myString {get; set;}
```

Is the line above the same thing as what follows which has a blocking variable explicitly declared:

```
public string myString {
    get { return m_myString; }
    set { m_myString = value; }
}
private string m_myString;
```

Now turning to VB, is the following VB the same as the first line of C# at the top of this post?

```vb
Public Property myString() As String
```

Or do we have to write everything out as in:

```vb
Public Property myString() As String
    Get
        Return m_myString
    End Get
    Set
        m_myString = Value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_myString As String
```

This question is not really about whether or not one wants to use a backing variable, but simply how the syntax for declaring the property works in VB.

Comment: That is four times the same statement. only difference is that the private string is not available for the first and third statement.

Comment: The search term you want is "Auto-Implemented Properties".  It works for both VB and C#.

Comment: Difference between VB and C#: VB has the ability to add parameters to the property, Property procedures: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3dtbky.aspx

Comment: @TnTinMn Thanks for that reference.  I tried for some time to find references that would clarify my question regarding get/put declarations.  Sometimes we just don't know the right term to use when searching.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Both your comments are very helpful.  The VB ability to add parameters was something I didn't really understand, but that's substantive.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't quite the same. VB.Net generates a hidden private backing field for auto-implemented property `myString` called `_myString`. This example will compile:

```vb
Public Property myString As String

Public Function Foo() As String
    Return myString
End Function

Public Function _Foo() As String
    Return _myString
End Function
```

Try the same in C#. It does not compile.

```
public string myString { get; set; }

public string Foo()
{
    return myString;
}

public string _Foo()
{
    return _myString; //The name '_myString' does not exist in the current context
}
```

Appropriately, you would then be able to declare the field `_myString` in C#, but not in VB.Net.

**So**

```vb
Private _myString As String

Public Property myString As String
    Get
        Return _myString
    End Get
    Set
        _myString = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

**=**

```vb
Public Property myString As String
```

**=**

```
private string _myString;

public string myString
{
    get { return _myString; }
    set { _myString = value; }
}
```

**!=** (**<>** for you VB.Net people)

```
public string myString { get; set; }
```

Comment: @djv Very illustrative response. Thx. Your sample really shows the shorthand VB declaration creates the backing variable & that it is available, though I doubt it's a good idea to ever use it.  I also appreciated your != / <> confirmation there is a difference with the shorthand C# declaration.  I suppose everything was down voted (even my question) b/c someone thinks it's too basic or not researched well, but as I commented above, I tried. I just didn't know how to search it out properly; I thought that's part of what SO was for. Nice well targeted answer, though.

Comment: So I'm guessing the only reason to longhand write a property declaration is if we need to do something special during the get or set?  Is that correct?

Comment: Interesting thing that `Public ReadOnly MyString` - not actually readonly, because it can be changed through generated `_MyString` member :)

Comment: @Fabio no, because `Public ReadOnly MyString` is a field, not a property, so it doesn't generate a backing field as above. Say you added `Property` to the declaration, then you would be forced to add a `Get`, so in short, a `ReadOnly Property` doesn't work the same as non-`ReadOnly`.

Comment: @djv, it was my typo - `Public ReadOnly Property MyString As String` is valid declaration of readonly property, which can be assigned only in declaration or constructor (Roslyn compiler feature). Setting `MyString = "new value"` somewhere else will not compile. But setting `_MyString = "new value"` works perfectly and update property value from anywhere of that class. - So `ReadOnly Property` in vb.net can be somehow confusing and lead in the difficult to find bugs

Comment: @Fabio maybe I'm missing something but I can't declare `Public ReadOnly Property MyString As String` in any .NET framework version.

Comment: @djv - [Auto-Implemented Properties (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) - you should have Roslyn compiler - VS 2015 or above. In same article is good explanation about "backing field" too

Comment: @fabio Ah, I am using VS2012 :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the C# `public string MyString { get; set; }` is equivalent to `Public Property MyString() As String` in VB.NET.

Note, property names should be upper camel case, AKA Pascal case.

Comment: Not quite. Now, try declaring string `_MyString` in both languages.

Comment: @djv Thanks for adding the explanation below